# Content-based action selection Web API using FiveLevelsOfMediaType (5LMT) not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to implement a RESTful API that uses commands to alter the state of the system (based on CQRS strategy).  By default Web API's routing will have difficulty matching to actions based on examining the object parameter's type. To get around this I've been using the following guide:
[Content Based Action Selection Using Five Levels of Media Type](http://byterot.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/Content-based-action-selection-ASP.NET-Web-API-REST-5LMT-Five-Levels-Of-Media-Type.html)

After following the instructions it still results in an ambiguous match exception, caused by overloaded Put methods in my controller.

My WebApiConfig is as follows:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.AddFiveLevelsOfMediaType();
    }
}
```

My controller looks like:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    public ProductDTO Get(int id)
    {
        var query = new ProductByIdQuery { Id = id };
        ProductDTO product = _queryBus.Dispatch(query);
        return product;
    }

    public void Put(ChangeProductCodeCommand command)
    {
        _commandBus.Dispatch(command);
    }

    public void Put(SetProductParentCommand command)
    {
        _commandBus.Dispatch(command);
    }

    public ProductsController(IQueryBus queryBus, ICommandBus commandBus)
    {
        _queryBus = queryBus;
        _commandBus = commandBus;
    }

    IQueryBus _queryBus;
    ICommandBus _commandBus;
}
```

On the client side, the http header I send is:

```
PUT /api/products HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;domain-model=ChangeProductCodeCommand
```

And the JSON:

```
{
  ProductId: 758,
  ProductCode: "TEST"
}
```

Results in:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Ambiguous Match",
  "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "StackTrace": "   at       ApiActionSelection.System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at ApiActionSelection.System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 3):

With two `Put` methods that differ only by parameter type, Web API is attempting to resolve to the correct action based on the type of the incoming parameter.

Unless the default model binder can map the incoming JSON to a complex type you have implemented, and that type matches the parameter type of one of your `Put` methods, then Web API will respond with the `"Ambiguous Match"` exception you are seeing because it can't determine which method to call. Note that by default Web API will not use your `Content-Type` header in action resolution.

I suggest reading [Routing and Action Selection in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection) so you understand how routing is working internally. Then you might want to create you own implementation of `IHttpActionSelector` where you examine your `Content-Type` and you can route the request to the action of your choice. You can find a sample implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/MikeJansen/4017214#file-jsonpcorsactionselector-cs).

You can also read more on model binding [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) to see how your incoming JSON can get resolved to one of your types.